# How to use a local directory csv file instead of hard coding in the codes?

Tags: html, csv, d3.js, visualization, bar-chart

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- Generated with d3-generator.com -->
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Bar Chart</title>
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
  </head>    
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
    <script>

function renderChart() {

/*var data = d3.csv.("Cancer_No_Of_Deaths_per_100000.csv", function(d) {
});*/
var data = d3.csv.parse(d3.select('#csv').text());
```

The line above is using the hard coded script for the csv file below.
I would like to change the code into something like var data = d3.csv.("myFile.csv") but there is nothing appearing when I changed it. So I would like to seek for help to see what is the correct way for me to be able to change the reading of the csv file from the local directory instead of hard coding the csv in the script like the codes above.

```
var valueLabelWidth = 40; // space reserved for value labels (right)
var barHeight = 20; // height of one bar
var barLabelWidth = 100; // space reserved for bar labels
var barLabelPadding = 5; // padding between bar and bar labels (left)
var gridLabelHeight = 18; // space reserved for gridline labels
var gridChartOffset = 3; // space between start of grid and first bar
var maxBarWidth = 420; // width of the bar with the max value

// accessor functions 
var barLabel = function(d) { return d['country'] + " " + d['gender']; };
var barValue = function(d) { return parseFloat(d['deaths']); };


// scales
var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(d3.range(0, data.length)).rangeBands([0, data.length * barHeight]);
var y = function(d, i) { return yScale(i); };
var yText = function(d, i) { return y(d, i) + yScale.rangeBand() / 2; };
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(data, barValue)]).range([0, maxBarWidth]);
// svg container element
var chart = d3.select('#chart').append("svg")
  .attr('width', maxBarWidth + barLabelWidth + valueLabelWidth)
  .attr('height', gridLabelHeight + gridChartOffset + data.length * barHeight);
// grid line labels
var gridContainer = chart.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + barLabelWidth + ',' + gridLabelHeight + ')'); 
gridContainer.selectAll("text").data(x.ticks(10)).enter().append("text")
  .attr("x", x)
  .attr("dy", -3)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(String);
// vertical grid lines
gridContainer.selectAll("line").data(x.ticks(10)).enter().append("line")
  .attr("x1", x)
  .attr("x2", x)
  .attr("y1", 0)
  .attr("y2", yScale.rangeExtent()[1] + gridChartOffset)
  .style("stroke", "#ccc");
// bar labels
var labelsContainer = chart.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (barLabelWidth - barLabelPadding) + ',' + (gridLabelHeight + gridChartOffset) + ')'); 
labelsContainer.selectAll('text').data(data).enter().append('text')
  .attr('y', yText)
  .attr('stroke', 'none')
  .attr('fill', 'black')
  .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align: middle
  .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
  .text(barLabel);
// bars
var barsContainer = chart.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + barLabelWidth + ',' + (gridLabelHeight + gridChartOffset) + ')'); 
barsContainer.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter().append("rect")
  .attr('y', y)
  .attr('height', yScale.rangeBand())
  .attr('width', function(d) { return x(barValue(d)); })
  .attr('stroke', 'white')
  .attr('fill', 'steelblue');
// bar value labels
barsContainer.selectAll("text").data(data).enter().append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(barValue(d)); })
  .attr("y", yText)
  .attr("dx", 3) // padding-left
  .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align: middle
  .attr("text-anchor", "start") // text-align: right
  .attr("fill", "black")
  .attr("stroke", "none")
  .text(function(d) { return d3.round(barValue(d), 2); });
// start line
barsContainer.append("line")
  .attr("y1", -gridChartOffset)
  .attr("y2", yScale.rangeExtent()[1] + gridChartOffset)
  .style("stroke", "#000");

}
    </script>
    <script id="csv" type="text/csv">country,year,gender,deaths
Afghanistan,2008,Female,97
Afghanistan,2008,Male,108

</script>
    <script>renderChart();</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [`d3.csv`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#csv) executes asynchronously, so you need to pass it a *callback function*. For example, you could place the code that creates a chart in a function called `createChart(data)`, and then call `d3.csv("myFile.csv", createChart)`.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti The cs file is     <script id="csv" type="text/csv">country,year,gender,deaths
Afghanistan,2008,Female,97
Afghanistan,2008,Male,108

</script>

Comment: @mdml I tried to modify the code that you have stated but there is still nothing being shown on the website.

Comment: First check that your data is being read in. You can do: `d3.csv('myFile.csv', function(data){ console.log(data); })` and see if you have a data object output to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`d3.csv`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#csv) executes asynchronously, so you need to pass it a *callback function*. For example, you could have your `data` be an argument to `renderChart`, and then call `d3.csv("myFile.csv", renderChart)`. Making this change produces the following chart on my machine:

[image]

Here's the updated Javascript:

```
var data = d3.csv("myFile.csv", renderChart);

function renderChart(data) {

    var valueLabelWidth = 40; // space reserved for value labels (right)
    var barHeight = 20; // height of one bar
    var barLabelWidth = 100; // space reserved for bar labels
    var barLabelPadding = 5; // padding between bar and bar labels (left)
    var gridLabelHeight = 18; // space reserved for gridline labels
    var gridChartOffset = 3; // space between start of grid and first bar
    var maxBarWidth = 420; // width of the bar with the max value

    // accessor functions 
    var barLabel = function (d) {
        return d['country'] + " " + d['gender'];
    };
    var barValue = function (d) {
        return parseFloat(d['deaths']);
    };


    // scales
    var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(d3.range(0, data.length)).rangeBands([0, data.length * barHeight]);
    var y = function (d, i) {
        return yScale(i);
    };
    var yText = function (d, i) {
        return y(d, i) + yScale.rangeBand() / 2;
    };
    var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(data, barValue)]).range([0, maxBarWidth]);
    // svg container element
    var chart = d3.select('#chart').append("svg")
        .attr('width', maxBarWidth + barLabelWidth + valueLabelWidth)
        .attr('height', gridLabelHeight + gridChartOffset + data.length * barHeight);
    // grid line labels
    var gridContainer = chart.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + barLabelWidth + ',' + gridLabelHeight + ')');
    gridContainer.selectAll("text").data(x.ticks(10)).enter().append("text")
        .attr("x", x)
        .attr("dy", -3)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(String);
    // vertical grid lines
    gridContainer.selectAll("line").data(x.ticks(10)).enter().append("line")
        .attr("x1", x)
        .attr("x2", x)
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("y2", yScale.rangeExtent()[1] + gridChartOffset)
        .style("stroke", "#ccc");
    // bar labels
    var labelsContainer = chart.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (barLabelWidth - barLabelPadding) + ',' + (gridLabelHeight + gridChartOffset) + ')');
    labelsContainer.selectAll('text').data(data).enter().append('text')
        .attr('y', yText)
        .attr('stroke', 'none')
        .attr('fill', 'black')
        .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align: middle
    .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
        .text(barLabel);
    // bars
    var barsContainer = chart.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + barLabelWidth + ',' + (gridLabelHeight + gridChartOffset) + ')');
    barsContainer.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter().append("rect")
        .attr('y', y)
        .attr('height', yScale.rangeBand())
        .attr('width', function (d) {
        return x(barValue(d));
    })
        .attr('stroke', 'white')
        .attr('fill', 'steelblue');
    // bar value labels
    barsContainer.selectAll("text").data(data).enter().append("text")
        .attr("x", function (d) {
        return x(barValue(d));
    })
        .attr("y", yText)
        .attr("dx", 3) // padding-left
    .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align: middle
    .attr("text-anchor", "start") // text-align: right
    .attr("fill", "black")
        .attr("stroke", "none")
        .text(function (d) {
        return d3.round(barValue(d), 2);
    });
    // start line
    barsContainer.append("line")
        .attr("y1", -gridChartOffset)
        .attr("y2", yScale.rangeExtent()[1] + gridChartOffset)
        .style("stroke", "#000");

}
```

Comment: It's working now. Thank you much for your explanations and I am enlightened more about how does the d3.csv actually works now. Appreciate your help and your effort.